# SQL запросы в Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Могу ли я в контексте Spring + Hibernate сделать простой sql запрос и получить список элементов ( как в JDBC  - ResultSet) для запроса данных из таблицы, не входящей в ORM модель? Или для этого нужно прикручивать JDBC соединение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас уже настроено подключение, то можно заинжектить `EntityManager`

```
@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;

public void myFunc(){
  List<Object[]> list = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM table").getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Что за объект я получу в результате этого запроса. Допустим, у меня в таблице есть 3 колонки. Как достать данные? И надо достать не одну запись, а 50

Comment: @alex, ну это уже другой разговор, изменил функцию

Comment: Благодарю.......